# c++ Iterating over a list of objects and deleting a object

Tags: c++, list, object, iterator

I have a list of objects and I want to delete a certain object once it hits the if condition. But I am having issues with it working. Mostly because the if condition is throwing the error.

Also I don't know if I need to create a temp folder value and let that be my if condition? I'm honestly kind of confused on iterators and any extra information might be helpful.

```
void removeFolder(string fName)
{
    list<Folder> folders = this->getFolders();
    for (list<Folder> itr = folders.begin(); itr != folders.end();)
    {
        if (fName == *itr)
            itr = folders.erase(itr);
        else
            ++itr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a `Folder` the same as a `folder`? And have you written an operator that will allow you to test the equality of `fName` (which is a `string`) and `*itr` (which is a `folder`)?

Comment: You are comparing a `string` with a `Folder`. If you have a function that returns the name of a `Folder`, you can use that. E.g. `if ( fName == (*iter).getName() )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have correct idea, but you are doing wrong thing. folders is:

```
list<Folder> folders
```

Than you are iterating different elements "folder" not "Folder":

```
for (list<folder> itr = folders.begin(); itr != folders.end();)
```

I think this should be rather:

```
for (list<Folder>::iterator itr = folders.begin(); itr != folders.end();)
```

Now once you are iterating correct objects make comparisons that make sense, not string to object:

```
if (fName == *itr)
```

but rather compare string to string, I assume your Folder class has some method to get folder name i.e:

```
if (fName == (*itr).getFolderName())
```

Comment: This would modify a local variable `folders` which will be destroyed after the function exits. That's not the intent, I am guessing.

Comment: An alternative is `if (*itr == fName)` and have an `operator==` that compares `Folder` with `string`. [Suggestions on how to write the overload.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is this question answered somewhere already, but the code is simple:

You only need to use `std::list<Folder>::remove_if()`.

```
void removeFolder(const std::string& fName)
{
    std::list<Folder>& folders = getFolders();
    folders.remove_if([&fName](Folder& item){return item.name == fName;});
}
```

As others have noted, there are other problems with your code that I've tried to fix. In particular, you are probably comparing some sort of `name` member with the `fName` variable. Also there is no need to pass the `fName` string by value into the `removeFolder` function, and presumably you need to modify not a local copy of `folders`, but some list existing outside of the function.

Comment: The member function `list<T>::remove_if` is a different thing from the non-member function `std::remove_if`. The member does not return an iterator, and includes the erase operations so does not need to be followed with any `erase()` call.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know. Fixed.

Comment: Since C++17 introduced `std::string_view`, one should prefer passing a `std::string_view` over a `std::string const&` for flexibility and efficiency, unless the 0-terminator is actually needed. Unfortunately, there's no variant with guaranteed 0-terminator. Also, consider wider application of `auto`.